# Can't seem to create user in MySQL console (ERROR 1064 (42000))

Tags: mysql

Now I'm no MySQL pro, but I've been using it for a good 5-6 years and I've never come across this:

- I log into my server via SSH
- I log into MySQL via `mysql -u root -pSUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD`
- I write: `CREATE USER 'magical_username'@'locahost' IDENTIFIED BY 'super_magical_password';`

Now this is where it gets weird. I expect the query to work and I can go about granting permissions, but, I get this instead:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'magical_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'super_magical_password' at line 1`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really an answer but a solution to the problem:

It turns out that the magical sysadmin, in all his wisdom, thought it was a good idea to copy over MySQL's raw DB files rather than doing a dump and import. This, coupled with incorrect permissions and MySQL versions, meant that MySQL had a big issue with users and granting, but serving the data was fine (that's why it seemed really weird).

Long story short: rebuilt the box and imported the data the correct way :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had exactly the same problem. For me it was because I was using a much older MySQL installation - version 4.1.20. The CREATE USER syntax was only introduced in version 5.x. For older 4.x databases you need to use something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON horsedb.* TO 'mrhorse'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass123'
```

Answer (score 0):

does the equivalent [`GRANT USAGE ON ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) version work?